# Subprocess does not execute Rscript

Tags: python, subprocess, python-os

I need to run Rscript from Python and wait until it finishes. As far as I know, `subprocess` is  more preferable than `os.system(command)`.

This is my current code:

```
import subprocess
command = "Rscript myscript.r -f 1"
subprocess.call([command])
# run some Python code
```

It gives me the following error message:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Rscript
>   myscript.r -f 1'

Just to mention that `os.system(command)` worked well, but it was not waiting until the script `myscript.r` finishes.

Comment: try `subprocess.call(command.split())`. Not ideal but works. this isn't going to wait either, though… are you on windows?

Answer (score 1):

`command` is the command *line*, not the command. Passing `command` in a list of 1 element tries to run `"Rscript myscript.r -f 1"` as a command.

Splitting into arguments (manually, which allows to pass parameters containing spaces too) is the best way:

```
subprocess.call(["Rscript","myscript.r","-f","1"])
```

Note that it does roughly the same as `os.system` (except that `os.system` 1) is unsafe 2) doesn't handle quoting)

So it's not going to wait for command to complete. On Windows, we could try to prefix with `cmd /c` to avoid that command detaches:

```
subprocess.call(["cmd","/c","Rscript","myscript.r","-f","1"])
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I force it to wait? Should I instead do something like this?: `r = subprocess.Popen(...)`, and the `r.wait()`

Comment: No, I am not on Windows. I am on ubuntu

Comment: @Fluxy I don't think it would work. That's already what `call` does. The way the process is launched is the issue. But as `Rscript` is the command to run scripts, I doubt that it's not blocking. Are you sure it's not waiting? have you inserted for instance a long delay in your script just to see?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html In the docs of `subprocess.call` I see `Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete`. Probably it refers to something different, right? So, does it mean that there is no way to do it in Ubuntu?

Comment: problem is: if the command detaches from shell, call won't make it attach on it. I don't have ubuntu or Rscript handy. You could try to add `"sh","-c"` arguments first...

Comment: Ok, let me try it.

Comment: When I run `subprocess.call(command.split())`, I get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Rscript'`. I also tried `subprocess.call([command.split()])`...

Comment: try with `shell=True` parameter. `subprocess.call(""Rscript myscript.r -f 1",shell=True)` just in case. Note that I'm discouraging to split command using split. Better compose it manually as a list.

Comment: In this case I get error `/bin/sh: 1: Rscript: not found`